# Installing MISP on Ubuntu Server running on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm currently trying to install [MISP](https://www.misp-project.org/index.html) on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ using Ubuntu Server, but it does not seem to be compatible with the Arm implementation of Ubuntu- I presume due to missing or unsupported dependencies.

Is it possible to run MISP on a RPi at all, using another OS, or is it not yet possible on Arm devices?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not seem to be compatible"_? You have the source code; you should be able to compile it on any platform.

Comment: You may need to add more details about what you tried and what issues you encountered.